# f.check_box checked => true for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I have the following code on my view:

```
//I write a loop here to display some workflows saying wkf.each do |i|
<% if (i write my condition here) %>
  <td style="text-align:left;">
  <%= f.check_box :i, {:checked=>true}%> 
  <%= f.label(i, i)%>
  </td></tr>
<% else %>
  <td style="text-align:left;">
  <%= f.check_box(i)%> 
  <%= f.label(i, i)%>
  </td></tr>
<%end%>
```

Suppose that there are three workflows 'A', 'B' and 'C' and 'C' meets the if condition, 
then the parameters being sent are 'A'=>0, 'B'=>0 and 'i'=>'1'.
I want it to be sent as 'C'=>'1' in the same way as 'A'=>0.

I know that '`i' =>'1'` is sent because i wrote `f.check_box :i, {:checked=>true}`% instead of
`<%= f.check_box(i)%>`.

Please let me know how to change this so that, the check box is checked by default when the if condition is met and the `#{i}` would be sent instead of `:i`

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `f.check_box :i` is not equal to `f.check_box(i)`, the difference is that the `i` is a variable, while `:i` is a symbol, which is almost like a string. Remove the `:` in the first case.

```
<%= f.check_box i, {:checked=>true} %>
```